# Flowtype Cannot get .clientHeight because property clientHeight is missing in Node [prop-missing]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to either set nextSibling or previousSibling on an html element but it's returning this I don't understand.

```
   let selectedElement: ?HTMLElement;
      const setOptionRef = ref => {
        selectedElement = ref;
      };
    
   const handleScrolling = (direction: number) => {
    const container = containerRef.current;

    // Based on keyboard navigation we get the next or previuos option
    // When we reach the start or end of the list, move to the start or end of the list based on the direction
    const nextOption =
      direction > 0
        ? selectedElement?.nextSibling
        : selectedElement?.previousSibling;

    // Handles which option to display once we've hit the end of the list range
    const endRangeOption =
      direction > 0
        ? container?.firstChild?.firstChild
        : container?.firstChild?.lastChild;

    const selectedOption: HTMLElement = nextOption || endRangeOption;

    // If one of these nodes is missing exit early
    if (!container || !selectedOption) return;

    const containerHeight: number = container.getClientRects()[0]?.height;
    const overScroll: number = selectedOption?.offsetHeight / 3;

    const scrollPos: number =
      selectedOption?.offsetTop +
      selectedOption?.clientHeight -
      containerHeight +
      overScroll;

    container.scrollTop = scrollPos;
   };
```

I keep getting these Flow type errors:

> Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> src/Typeahead.js:175:40
>
> Cannot get selectedOption?.offsetHeight because property offsetHeight
> is missing in Node [1]. [prop-missing]
>
> ```
>  packages/gestalt/src/Typeahead.js
>  172│     if (!container || !selectedOption) return;
>  173│
>  174│     const containerHeight = container.getClientRects()[0].height;
>  175│     const overScroll = selectedOption?.offsetHeight / 3;
>  176│
>  177│     const scrollPos =
>  178│       selectedOption.offsetTop +
>
>  /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_349b825f/dom.js  [1] 608│   nextSibling: ?Node;
> ```
>
> Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> src/Typeahead.js:175:40
>
> Cannot get selectedOption?.offsetHeight because property offsetHeight
> is missing in Node [1]. [prop-missing]
>
> ```
>  packages/gestalt/src/Typeahead.js
>  172│     if (!container || !selectedOption) return;
>  173│
>  174│     const containerHeight = container.getClientRects()[0].height;
>  175│     const overScroll = selectedOption?.offsetHeight / 3;
>  176│
>  177│     const scrollPos =
>  178│       selectedOption.offsetTop +
>
>  /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_349b825f/dom.js  [1] 615│   previousSibling: ?Node;
> ```
>
> Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> src/Typeahead.js:178:22
>
> Cannot get selectedOption.offsetTop because property offsetTop is
> missing in Node [1]. [prop-missing]
>
> ```
>  packages/gestalt/src/Typeahead.js
>  175│     const overScroll = selectedOption?.offsetHeight / 3;
>  176│
>  177│     const scrollPos =
>  178│       selectedOption.offsetTop +
>  179│       selectedOption.clientHeight -
>  180│       containerHeight +
>  181│       overScroll;
>
>  /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_349b825f/dom.js  [1] 608│   nextSibling: ?Node;
> ```
>
> Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> src/Typeahead.js:178:22
>
> Cannot get selectedOption.offsetTop because property offsetTop is
> missing in Node [1]. [prop-missing]
>
> ```
>  packages/gestalt/src/Typeahead.js
>  175│     const overScroll = selectedOption?.offsetHeight / 3;
>  176│
>  177│     const scrollPos =
>  178│       selectedOption.offsetTop +
>  179│       selectedOption.clientHeight -
>  180│       containerHeight +
>  181│       overScroll;
>
>  /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_349b825f/dom.js  [1] 615│   previousSibling: ?Node;
> ```
>
> Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> src/Typeahead.js:179:22
>
> Cannot get selectedOption.clientHeight because property clientHeight
> is missing in Node [1]. [prop-missing]
>
> ```
>  packages/gestalt/src/Typeahead.js
>  176│
>  177│     const scrollPos =
>  178│       selectedOption.offsetTop +
>  179│       selectedOption.clientHeight -
>  180│       containerHeight +
>  181│       overScroll;
>  182│
>
>  /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_349b825f/dom.js  [1] 608│   nextSibling: ?Node;
> ```
>
> Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
> src/Typeahead.js:179:22
>
> Cannot get selectedOption.clientHeight because property clientHeight
> is missing in Node [1]. [prop-missing]
>
> ```
>  packages/gestalt/src/Typeahead.js
>  176│
>  177│     const scrollPos =
>  178│       selectedOption.offsetTop +
>  179│       selectedOption.clientHeight -
>  180│       containerHeight +
>  181│       overScroll;
>  182│
>
>  /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_349b825f/dom.js  [1] 615│   previousSibling: ?Node;
> ```

Comment: Can you confirm that `selectedElement` has whatever value you expect it to have?

Comment: It does, the code works as intended

Comment: Seems like you really want `selectedOption: ?HTMLElement` with a questionmark, and you want `.nextElementSibling` and `.firstElementChild` and such. Right now you're getting a `Node`, not an `Element`, because there could be text nodes or comments.

Comment: Im getting compatibility issues between HTMLElement and Element, they aren't treated as the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting errors for `offsetHeight` because flow cannot verify what the object is to do proper type checking. In the code snippet you gave above you assigned `selectedOption` as `HTMLElement` immediately which isn't sound because without using any logical conditions how can you be sure `selectedOption` will be `HTMLElement` and not `null` or `undefined`?

```
const selectedOption: HTMLElement = nextOption || endRangeOption;
```

Instead you should remove the type assignment here because at this point you're still not sure what the value of it is, then in the next statement change your `if` condition to validate the object type:

```
if (!container || !(selectedOption instanceof HTMLElement)) return;
```

Now any code you write from this line onwards will be under the constraint that `selectedOption` is of type `HTMLElement` so all your flow errors should be fixed.